# Do I need an VPN or VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn

I'm mixing these up I'm afraid.

I have my own web crawler written in PhantomJS that collects some data for m (from a site that provides no API), I've been testing it on my own computer and it looks quite good, what I want to do now is to have some remote computer on which I'd be able to run my crawler and see how it performs 24/7.

I'm not entirely sure what I actually need. If I want to crawl the web only do I need a Virtual Machine, with GUI and stuff? I've found [Windows Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/#Linux) but the cheapest option is 12-20 USD/month which is, quite a lot. What's the cheapest way to achieve what I want? Especially if I'd want to run more than 1 crawlers at a time  might need more machines running, even at 10 bucks a month it could cost a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What you might consider, is looking at a DigitalOcean container.

Containers are a form of a Virtual Machine, but the kernel is on the host of the VM, which means that the size of the container and the resource usage is lower. There are a lot of other container providing services, so do some research on that.